# Remix multiple form submissions

Tags: remix.run

I have a form that upon submitting multiple times, I see in the network tab the cancelled requests. but I still receive them in the action function.
Am I missing something? Is this the right behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when a `fetch` *request* (which Remix uses under the hood) is aborted, it simply cancels the processing of the *response*. It does *not* stop the server from processing that request. You should make sure your server can handle multiple requests being sent.

Comment: Thank @kiliman, It does handle all the requests, this is my problem. In my case, it calls a third party api on all the requests, even the cancelled ones, what is the best approach to this problem? –